# csrf token in bluemix deployed node instance

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, csrf, alchemyapi

Hi I used the deploy to bluemix button at the top right of this page

https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=69990450306114782046823&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1478206651

to create an Alchemy language node server. It runs ok -

https://alchemylanguage-nodejs-encekxdev-216.mybluemix.net/

but when I try to post to it using postman I get the response 'internal server error'.

Checking the server logs, it seems to respond to the request with

> code: 'EBADCSRFTOKEN', error: 'invalid csrf token'

Even if I try to send the csrf from the webpage version of the site, it still doesn't work.

I feel like I have missed something in the configuration of the server but don't know what. I'm not great with servers etc so sorry if this is super basic.

EDIT - I should mention I have also tried sending an apikey in the request which I got from the service credentials section in the alchemy service bit off the dashboard but the same error occurs.

EDIt - The call to the API I am making looks like this:

> POST https://alchemylanguage-nodejs-encekxdev-216.mybluemix.net/api/keywords

with headers:

> text: 'this is some dummy text I have made'

I have also tried adding apikey to the headers.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add more details on your post request? Which API are you using? I tried with some APIs and post is working fine for me (both using curl and postman).

Comment: Thanks @AlexdaSilva for trying it out - I have edited the question to show which API I am using (I think - if not please feel free to direct me). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not POST your application, you have to POST to the API.
Here is the link with API URL and various samples:

http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1

For example, here is a curl request for keywords:

`curl -X POST \
-d "outputMode=json" \
-d "url=http://www.twitter.com/ibmwatson" \
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/url/URLGetRankedKeywords?apikey=$API_KEY"`

Make sure you export `$API_KEY`to your environment before running the command above. You can find the `$API_KEY` in the AlchemyAPI instance you created in Bluemix.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry if I am missing the point but I am using the Node server the wizard off their page created which has this route for me to post to (their demo page posts to this too)

app.post('/api/:method', function(req, res, next) {
  var method = req.params.method;
  if (typeof alchemyLanguage[method] === 'function') {
    alchemyLanguage[method](req.body, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.json(response);
    });
  } else {
    next({code: 404, error: 'Unknown method: ' + method });
  }
});

what do I add?

Comment: the sample application is secured with the csurf npm package. This package requires an initial communication to exchange the crsf token between client and server, so you will not be able to send a post command from postman (this package is exactly to avoid this). You can find more details here: https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf. Again, if you want to just send post commands you can use the Watson API directly as I mentioned in my answer, it does not make sense to try to use the API via the sample application.